# Change library override colors in Blender theme

Tags: interface, theme

I know how to change theme colors in Blender. That's easy. But I can't find the specific UI element I'm looking for in the theme editor, and there is no search function.

There is a pair of colors that display that a value is library overridable but has not been changed, or that it has been changed.

I cannot for the life of me figure out where in the massive pile of options in the theme editing screen those colors actually live. Can anyone point me to where they are, so I can change them?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the UI element you are looking for? I recently changed my colors, and also went through the headache of finding what option changes what element (some were truly confounding), though I did not document it. Maybe I can help while it's still fresh in my memory.

Comment: Specifically some UI elements, including numerical fields (Like location and rotation, etc), take on a particular color when they are part of an object that is in a library override. If those values are changed from their original values, they take on a different color to indicate that state. (though this color change is overridden if they are keyframed, because then the keyframed value color is what shows)
Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. Maybe that's a bit more intricate than I was thinking. - I guess I was expecting "what is the name given to the toolbar background" or something like that ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what it's actually called. Which makes it hard to find it XD

Comment: Well, to help narrow it down, where do you see this in the UI  {ex: 3Dview, properties, file manager, etc...) and in what form (number field, value slider, text box)? Also, what color is it by default?

Comment: Anywhere that there is a numeric value associated with any object or bone contained in the library override. I'm not using the standard color scheme, but if I select a normal object, values like the location and custom properties (wherever in the UI they are shown, properties, 3D view sidebar, for example) have a grey background with white text, just like any other numeric value for any other object. If I change the value, ONLY if the object/bone is part of a library override, the background becomes blue-green. For any other normal local object it stays grey. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is it, but I'm putting as an answer so I can post the pic - Are any of these the elements you're looking to change (Specifically the blue and orange - overridden/changed)?

[image: UIColors]

Comment: That's it! That was what I was looking for. Thank you! :D